# Error when loading fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to android studio and am having some trouble with starting a fragment from an activity. I used code from on here to display the fragment and it was working up until now. I am using a third party library called 'DecoView' which needs to extend fragment, all the code is in 'LineDetails' (its too long to add all code). Does anyone recognise this error below?

Thank you in advance!

LINE DETAILS XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/dynamicArcView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    </com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/actual"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Actual"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textPercentage"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dynamicArcView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actual_btn"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actualbutton"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewProgress"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/actual"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProgress"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actual"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/actual_btn"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/textPercentage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLineType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#f15623"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dynamicArcView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dynamicArcView" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/info"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:onClick="verifyButton"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have an error when inflating your xml
can you add `line_details.xml`*

Comment: it wont let me add all of the xml

Comment: line details xml added

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_name"
class="com.almac.tracker.LineDetails"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> **"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**
>   is missing

use below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_name"
        class="com.almac.tracker.LineDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I already it added at the top but thanks anyway, any other ideas?

Comment: post your R.layout.line_details file

Comment: it is added now

Comment: that's exactly what I have in fragment.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
    tools:context="com.yourpackagehere.FragmentThatIsInflatingTheXml">
```

to your first layout, the Relative one. Pls note that you have to change "yourpackagehere" with the name of your package and "FragmentThatIsInflatingTheXml" with the name of the actual Fragment

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.almac.tracker/com.almac.tracker.Actforfragmentname}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: I am still getting this error, if its any help to you

Comment: this error is given when you try to use a not primitive type on a xml's component without propperly setting it up on your Application, there's only one problem, once i encountered this error over the years, i simply changed it to the equivalent primitive type, so i'm not able to tell you if you need to set it up on Gradle or in the AndroidManifest file, just try searching something like "setting up new xml component Android"

Answer (score 0):

You said that DecoView extends a fragment so it should be added like this:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment_id"                  
  android:name="com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: added that line and still crashing

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?